# How to shift the position of badge in ion-tab which is title-only?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need the badge to come on the top-right of where the text ends, right now it's not like that - 
Here is the screenshot of the default implementation :

```
<ion-tab title="Business" badge="homeBadgeCount" badge-style="badge-assertive" href="#/tab/home">
```

[image: ion-tab badge]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made following changes to make it work :

1. Created a new CSS class to be used that positions the badge properly:

> ```
> .business-badge {
>   right: 32px !important;
> }
> ```

2. And used that class inside the html:

Hope it will be useful for someone who is not much familiar with css like me ;)